# How to merge cells using Spreadsheet::WriteExcel using Merge_range function?

Tags: perl, excel, spreadsheet

I have used [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.37/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm) for creating spreadsheet report.

I tried to merge some cells using merge_range() function.

> $worksheet->merge_range(3,5,9,4,$title,
>   $format);
>   [OR]
>
> $worksheet->merge_range('E3:I4',$title,
>   $format);
>
> $worksheet->write('F6',"LANGUAGE",$format);

it shows the error message like the following

> Error: refer to merge_range() in the
>   documentation. Can't use previously
>   merged format in non-merged cell

How to solve this. if I used `write()` .. that time only it shows the error. if I didn't used any write functions that time the above error message is not showing and the cells are merged.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you see the documentation of [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm) module, it states :

**WARNING:** The format object that is used with a merge_range() method call is marked internally as being associated with a merged range. It is a fatal error to use a merged format in a non-merged cell. Instead you should use separate formats for merged and non-merged cells. This restriction will be removed in a future release.

That means do not use format '$format' as used in the

`$worksheet->write('F6',"LANGUAGE",$format);`

Make two format one for merged cell other for non-merged cell.

Problem will be solved.